# Style components with `styles` prop or `className` prop + `mergeStyleSets`?

Tags: reactjs, office-ui-fabric-react, fluent-ui

New to Fluent UI React.

I have been tinkering around with the framework and read through all of its documentation that I can find. My understanding is that **CSS-in-JS** approach is encouraged when it comes to component styling. I see there are two ways to do so–via the `styles` prop and via the use of the `mergeStyleSets` utilities function + the `className` prop. Here is a [codepen](https://codepen.io/tamakisquare/pen/eYpjWWR) to illustrate what I mean here.

My question is, do they serve different use cases or are they pretty much the same? How do I decide which one to use? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I've tried both and am leaning more toward mergeStyleSets because it gives me one way to predictably target everything and I don't have to learn the "magic class names" buried deep within each component and what it does or does not affect. Having said that, for certain key components, like DataGrid, there's a lot of styling involved and the classes exposed are not too difficult to learn and are helpful for getting the best out of those components.

This is particularly the case when you have to do selectors for things like "hover" or "active" or "before/after".  Trying to get that working via magic class names exposed by "styles" was much more confusing for me than using the "mergeStyles" approach on the raw HTML directly.

So for me, I've been cherry picking from the framework, using it for color themes, elevation, and highly complicated components like DataGrid, but not for things like Stack or Stack Item.